# Laravel accessing app/storage files in public folder

Tags: laravel, path, permissions

I have some xml files that are stored in app/storage folder.
i want to include these files in my public folder xml files (public/js/us.xml). i should must load xml files from storage path that have write permission, these xml files are manipulated by php script. I have tried full absulute path but that does not works. (example markersUrl)

Comment: If must store these files in the storage I suggest you create a route / controller that returns them to your views

Comment: Example you could do this: `Route::get('/XML/{file_name}', function(){  });`